# qbo3 Dependency requires AND and OR

Tags: javascript, qbo3

We are trying to set up a complicated dependency for a field, where we need to do a combination of both `and` and `or` condition.

[image]

How do I implement:

```
(FieldA and FieldB) or FieldC
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, the qbo3 `Dependency` behavior does not support mixing `AND` with `OR`.

There are two workarounds.

## Custom Javascript

You can create a JS function along these lines:

```js
function requireComments() {  
  var fieldA = document.id('FieldA').value;  
  var fieldB = document.id('FieldB').value;  
  var fieldC = document.id('FieldC').value;  
  var commentField = document.id('ExceptionCommentsInput');
  var required = (fieldA && fieldB) || fieldC;  // same as (fieldA.value != '' && fieldB.value !='') || fieldC.value != '';  
  if (required) {    
    commentField.removeAttribute('disabled');    
    commentField.addClass('required');    
    commentField.removeClass('disabled');  
  } else {    
    commentField.setAttribute('disabled');    
    commentField.removeClass('required');    
    commentField.addClass('disabled');  
  }
}
```

Then, add `requireComments()` to the `onchange` handlers of `FieldA`, `FieldB`, and `FieldC`.

Pros:

- slightly less demanding on the browser
- no extra data being passed over the wire/saved to the task

Cons:

- Gotta do custom JS

## Hidden Fields

If you prefer to stay away from the custom JS, you can get where you need to go with some hidden fields.

Create a hidden field called `FielldAFieldB`, and make it dependent on `FieldA,FieldB` (AND).
Then, make `ExceptionCommentsInput` dependent on `FieldAFieldB,FieldC` (OR).

Pros:

- easy to configure and maintain

Cons:

- extra field (`FieldAFieldB`) passed over the wire/saved the task